# 2-port KVM switch mouse lag

Tags: mouse, kvm-switch

I hope I am posting this to the correct area...
I just purchased a StarTech SV211DPUA 2-port display port KVM switch. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I'm having an issue with the KVM where the mouse lags dramatically when using the KVM switch. When I mean lag, I mean I can move the mouse pointer and then the pointer pauses on its own for about 2 seconds and then it will allow me to use it again. The mouse I am using is a Logitech MX518.
Is there a file somewhere (Xorg?) that I can try to tweak to see if I can fix this lag issue?
Thanks ahead of time.